# 4SUM variation in quadratic complexity (Python 3.5)

Tags: python, algorithm, hashtable, big-o

I've been having a little bit of problem with a variation of the 4SUM problem. Essentially, we are required to choose one number, say `i`, `j`, `k`, `l` from 4 tuples of 500 integers each, say `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, such that `i+j+k+l == 0`. These integers range from `-20000` to `20000`. Currently, my code has a time complexity of *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* I believe. According to my instructor, this time complexity can be reduced even further, to either *O(n<sup>2</sup> log n)* or *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* (by using hash tables or something).

Unfortunately, if this hash tables method is the way to go, I am not sure how to go about implementing it. Hence if anyone could show me how to code this program in Python 3.5 I would be most grateful. (PS. please do try to use as few nested loops as possible, none would be ideal).

I have attached my code below for reference. If it is possible to modify my current code to reduce its time complexity, please do inform me as well.

```
import collections

import itertools


def selection(a, b, c, d):
    """program has 4 main parts,
        firstly, triple_sum finds possible 3sums in the list abc
        secondly, is_iterable ensures that inputs of tuple length 1 (ie. not iterable) are made iterable
        thirdly, main function determines if there exists possible a, b, c in abc that correspond to each d
        fourthly, main function checks if only 1 of the 3 integers from triple_sum exist in each array"""

    '''use sort O(n log n) to sort input array, then find possible 3sums in O(n^2)'''
    def triple_sum(a, res):
        a.sort()
        positions = collections.defaultdict(set)
        for i, n in enumerate(a):
            positions[n].add(i)
        for (i, ai), (j, aj) in itertools.combinations(enumerate(a), 2):
            n = res - ai - aj
            if positions[n].difference((i, j)):
                return n, ai, aj

    '''Ensure that all inputs are iterable'''
    def is_iterable(x):
        if isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
            return x
        else:
            return x,

    a, b, c, d = is_iterable(a), is_iterable(b), is_iterable(c), is_iterable(d)
    abc = a + b + c
    abc = [i for i in abc]

    '''find value of d which has corresponding a, b, c
        and returns appropriate value if conditions are met'''
    ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = 0, 0, 0, 0
    for i in d:
        x = 0 - i
        j = triple_sum(abc, x)
        if j[0] in a and j[1] in b and j[2] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[0], j[1], j[2], i
            break
        elif j[0] in a and j[2] in b and j[1] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[0], j[2], j[1], i
            break
        elif j[1] in a and j[0] in b and j[2] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[1], j[0], j[2], i
            break
        elif j[1] in a and j[2] in b and j[0] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[1], j[2], j[0], i
            break
        elif j[2] in a and j[0] in b and j[1] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[2], j[0], j[1], i
            break
        elif j[2] in a and j[1] in b and j[0] in c:
            ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d = j[2], j[1], j[0], i
            break
        else:
            continue

    return ans_a, ans_b, ans_c, ans_d
```

Thanks in advance :)

PS. If anyone needs more clarification or information do let me know.

Comment: I still not fully understand the problem. Can you given a (small) example to demonstrate what you aim to do?

Comment: for example, say the tuples are a = (5, 17, -8)
b = (-13, 19)
c = (6, -9, 10, 0)
d = (-14, 7) 
then the solution should be 17, -13, 10, -14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Theory

- Iterate over all the `(i,j)` pairs and create a dict with `i+j` as key and `(i,j)` as value
- Iterate over all the `(k,l)` pairs and create a dict with `-(k+l)` as key and `(k,l)` as value.
- Iterate over the keys of your first dict, and check if the second dict also has this key. In that case, `sum((i,j,k,l))` will be `0`.

Every described step is `O(n²)`, so the whole algorithm will be `O(n²)`, with `n` being the size of the tuples.

## Code

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]
c = [9, 10, 11, 12]
d = [13, 14, 15, -24]


def pairs_and_sums(list1, list2):
    return {(x + y): (x, y) for x in list1 for y in list2}


first_half = pairs_and_sums(a, b)
second_half = pairs_and_sums(c, d)

for i_plus_j in first_half:
    if -i_plus_j in second_half:
        i, j = first_half.get(i_plus_j)
        k, l = second_half.get(-i_plus_j)
        print("Solution found!")
        print("sum((%d,%d,%d,%d)) == 0" % (i, j, k, l))
        break
else:
    print "No solution found"
```

It outputs :

```
Solution found!
sum((4,8,12,-24)) == 0
```

Comment: What's the point of storing any values if you're not using them later? Might as well use a `set` then.

Comment: Use a set if you only want to know if there's a solution, use dicts to know what the solution is.

Comment: Uh @EricDuminil the problem is i am not sure how to create such a dictionary

Comment: Try it, it's really not that hard. I'm also working on some code.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! By the way, could you explain the difference between a list, a set, a dict, and a map? Because I've been seeing a lot of these terms in Google but don't quite understand them. Thanks!

Comment: A good explanation wouldn't fit in the comment. A list is an ordered succession of elements, possibly with duplicates. A set is a collection of unique elements, a dict is a collection of `(key, value)` pairs, with unique keys. The most important characteristic for your question is that it takes n steps to answer the question "does this list contain this element?" while it only takes 1 step to answer the question "does this set or dict contain this element?"

Comment: @EricDuminil Oh I see...thanks! Ur answer is rly helpful! :)